# How to use column in result set as parameter to FROM clause in a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have result set stored in a variable like this

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE([table] sysname, [column] sysname);
INSERT INTO @tmpTable
    SELECT tab1.name AS [table],
        col1.name AS [column] 
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
     INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
      ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
      ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
      ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
     INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
      ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
      ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
      ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
WHERE tab2.name = 'sometable'
```

This gives me a result set like this:

```
| table | column |
|-------|--------|
| tab1  | col4   |
| tab2  | col12  |
| tab2  | col1   |
```

What I need now is to query each table from the above result set and get the value of the column 'column' from that table.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about... Please edit your question and replace the `SELECT [...]` with meaningful sample data. Then add the expected output. (And please re-tag your question with the SQL-Server-Version tag)...

Comment: When a SQL engine executes a query it, by nature, "cycles" over all the records in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Dynamic SQL

```
create TABLE tmpTable ([table] sysname, [column] sysname);
INSERT INTO tmpTable
    SELECT tab1.name AS [table],
        col1.name AS [column] 
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
     INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
      ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
      ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
      ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
     INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
      ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
      ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
      ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
WHERE tab2.name = 'sometable'

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql=''
select @sql=@sql+' select '+[column]+' from '+[table] from tmpTable +' union all'

set @sql=substring(@sql,1,len(@sql)-9)

exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create the `SELECT`s dynamically and execute them within a `CURSOR` (one of the rare situations, where a cursor is a good choice):

Use the print to check, if the commands are what you need. Then take away the double minus before the `EXEC` to get them executed.

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 'SELECT ' + [column] + ' FROM ' + [table] + ';' 
    FROM @tmpTable;
OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    PRINT @cmd;
    --EXEC(@cmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```